# dojo filteringselect with option value '0'

Tags: dojo

i have following filteringselect:

```
<select name="v" dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" valueList="v" id="v" value="0"><option value=""></option><option value="0">0-test</option><option value="1">1-test2/option><option value="2">2-test3</option><option value="X">X-testx</option></select>
```

the strange thing is, that the empty option is selected by default allthough i set the value to '0'.

does anybody know this phenomenon?
regards,
gerhard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is defaulting selectedIndex=0 since you did not specify any option tag as selected originally.  This gives the widget 2 different initial values: 1) value="0" and 2) selectedIndex=0.  However, in this corner case, value == selectedIndex, which tells the widget to ignore value since some browsers set value=selectedIndex by default on select tags.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it! - it seems that when using filteringselects with inlined options, the option has to be marked as selected too.